# how to execute a php script after 15 minuits from form submition

Tags: php

need a big help again.

I'm developing a php system

once a user filed and submit a form then it should approved by a manager i made all the applications and every thing. but the thing is once the user submit an application if it is not approved by the manager within 15 Minuit an email should go to HOD. so i want to know how i execute a php script after 15 Minuit from form submit?

Comment: Store it in the database with the datetime when form was submitted and build cron to run every minute, and when >= 15 minutes passed, run your script.

Comment: that is probably the best way to go about doing this. keep in mind that, with a 15-minute interval, your email may only come after 29 minutes (if submitted 1 minute after an execution, it's 14 minutes old at next execution (not >= 15), and 29 minutes old at the next)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to run cron for every few minute and check whether its 15 min old..
if its fifteen minutes old then execute your process..

i think it will not consume much processing power but it depends on the task...

Answer (score 0):

Store an Entry for the submitted form in a database along with the time of submission, and setup a cron, which will run every minute, to check the 15 mins old unused entries and to shoot a mail.

exactly as mentioned in the comment by wriggler

Comment: will it effect to the process of the server?